# GetClipboardData() Cut vs. Copy

Tags: windows, winapi, clipboard

When [GetClipboardData()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039(v=vs.85).aspx) is used to access the data captured by the Clipboard, is there an API call or flag to distinguish between a Copy action (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and a Cut action (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)?

Comment: how `GetClipboardData` related to edit control behavior ?

Comment: You need to use `OleGetClipboard()` to get the OLE `IDataObject`, and then query it for `CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no generic way to know if data was placed on the clipboard because of a cut or copy action. In most applications "cut" is just "copy selection"+"delete selection".

As noted in the comments, [the shell has a clipboard format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT) called `CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT` but this format is mostly just used when "cutting" files/items in the shell. The shell calls this ["delete on paste"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#delete_on_paste).